# Package for C++ multivaiable linear regression

Tags: c++, linear-regression

I am currently using using `mlpack::regression` to do multivaiable linear regression.

All is good, the problem is that it does not handle invalid data gracefully. If there is no unique solution, the program is got killed.

If am wondering if there is a better package for linear regression.

Comment: Check out SVD (singular value decomposition). It's widely used to check for non-solutions or high levels of uncertainty in solutions. Sometimes you can get a good solution but one of the variables has no effect, or linear combination of two or more match hence count as less than the full number of variables. SVD will tell you if that happens. Eigen is a set of templates that does a good job with this sort of thing.